# Codeigniter Undefined offset: 0 when submitting form

Tags: php, codeigniter

Undefined offset: 0 error is happening in my edit data form after submitting.
Sometimes this works and most of the time it doesnt. any idea where the mistake is happening?

```
 function data_user_edit($id = ''){

$user = $this->adminmodel->selectdata('user where id_user = "'.$id.'"')->result_array();

            $data = array(
                'title'             => '.:: EVALUASI PROSES BELAJAR MENGAJAR GURU SMA NEGERI 4 BEKASI::. ',
                'titlesistem'       => $this->model->getTitle(),
                'nama'              => $user[0]["nama"],
                'id_user'           => $user[0]["id_user"],
                'status'            => 'edit',
                'username'          => $user[0]["username"],
                'password'          => $user[0]["password"],
                'level'             => $user[0]["level"],
                'tipeakun'          => $user[0]["tipeakun"],
        );

            $this->load->view('admin/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('admin/data_user_form');
            $this->load->view('admin/footer');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a scenario, especially with a public controller, where a user goes to your `somepage/data_user_edit` manually, and doesn't type in their id. This is the error they will get because `$user` is returning bool or no rows, thus `$user[0]` isn't defined.

First off, if it is a user edit page then I'm quite surprised you are allowing them the option to manually enter their id in to the url, and to presumably change the details of other users simply by changing the url. This should be gotten from a `session` variable, and they should have to be logged in to see even *reach* the page.

Secondly, you should always, as a matter of course, check if `num_rows() > 0` before attempting to access your `result`.

Thirdly you can just use `row_array()` for one record instead of `result_array()`. You wouldn't need `$user[0]` and could just use `$user`

e.g.

```
if (is_null($this->session->id)) {
    show_error('not allowed');
}

$id = $this->session->id;

$query = $this->adminmodel->selectdata('user where id_user = "'.$id.'"');

if ($query->num_rows() !== 1) {
    show_error('no user with id');
}

$user = $query->row_array();

            $data = array(
                'title'             => '.:: EVALUASI PROSES BELAJAR MENGAJAR GURU SMA NEGERI 4 BEKASI::. ',
                'titlesistem'       => $this->model->getTitle(),
                'nama'              => $user["nama"],
                'id_user'           => $user["id_user"],
                'status'            => 'edit',
                'username'          => $user["username"],
                'password'          => $user["password"],
                'level'             => $user["level"],
                'tipeakun'          => $user["tipeakun"],
        );

            $this->load->view('admin/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('admin/data_user_form');
            $this->load->view('admin/footer');
```

Comment: this is only for administrator, that can edit other users data. so any idea how to still make it work ?

Comment: then delete everything above `$query = $this->adminmodel->selectdata('user where id_user = "'.$id.'"');` and use it like you did before.

Answer (score 0):

Check `$user` empty or not and check it is valid which you code